# Как экспортировать экземпляр STL?

Tags: c++

```
#if defined(CORE_EXPORTS)
  #define MI_BASE_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define MI_BASE_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class MI_BASE_EXPORT log_message {
  // ...
  private:
    std::ostringstream _out_full_log; // warning: C4251
};
```

Я не понимаю, как мне использовать экземпляры STL в классе, чтобы избежать предупреждений.

Comment: Ну, можно, например, работать через указатель на `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: Если все пользователи этой dll будут собираться тем же компилятором, и при техже опциях (в т.ч. debug/release), то можно игнорировать это предупреждение.